# how to use Angular to call ajax and populate content from the return (after page has already rendered)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am a backend API developer, new to AngularJS (**version 1**), which is what my current assignment is written in.

The page has `ng-app="app"` found in the <html> tag, and `ng-controller="BaseController as baseCtrl"`, and renders just fine.

From here, there is a block of (currently server-side) content that needs to instead be called by ajax, post-render, because its source is unreliable and sometimes slow.  I've already written the API URL to return the content as e.g.

`{"status":"OK","id":"feed-whatsnew","content":"Unreliable source!"}`

My question is, how do I use Angular to populate the "content" above into the content portion of `<div id="feed-whatsnew"> .. <div class="content"></div>..</div>` position, and also unhide `feed-whatsnew`?

So far, angular rendering makes sense to me but any secondary process like this is still opaque.  I know how I would have handled it in jQuery but want to avoid trying to simply "mimic" a library vs. truly implementing the Angular framework.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS shipped with powerful `$http` library to perform the ajax. Please go through relatively easy documentation available at https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Here are the logical steps

1. Inject `$http` in controller dependency
2. Make service call through $http
3. On Success, assign the response to the $scope variable to make
   it available to UI/html markup. Assignment will differ if you are using controller `as` in the markup.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('BaseController', function($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.feed = null;

    _getDataFromServer();

    function _getDataFromServer() {
      var req = {
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
        method: 'GET' //could be post/put etc
          //data: someJson -- if webservice need so
      };

      $http(req)
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.feed = response.data;
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log('some error occured!', err);
        });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BaseController as vm">

  <p>Using $http</p>

  <div id="feed-whatsnew" ng-hide="!vm.feed">
    <!-- use {{}} or ng-bind to bind the data -->
    <!-- use ng-hide to show/hide the content conditionally -->
    Title from Ajax Response: {{vm.feed.title}}
    <div class="content">
      Content:
      <p ng-bind="vm.feed.body"></p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I got feedback from another developer that this is the best way.  Thanks.  Just curious what the perception of the `vm` acronym is.  Virtual Machine?  (Just a guess :) = seems to be a coding convention.

Comment: haha @OliverWilliams ya its convention to refer view model :) https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controlleras-with-vm

Answer (score 3):

In angular you could use the `$http`-provider to call an external API using ajax. Here's an example of how you would do that

```
app.controller('BaseController',['$http', function($http){
    var vm = this;
    vm.content = {};

    vm.fetchContent = function(){
        return $http.get('/my-api-endpoint').then(function(response){
            vm.content = response.data;
        }, function(response){
            console.error('Failed calling /my-api-endpoint ', response);
        });
    };

    // Initiallly load content
    vm.fetchContent();
}]);
```

The call to `$http.get(..)` start's an asynchronous call to your given external url and returns something called a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api). When the asynchronous call finishes, this Promise resolves, which executes the callback passed to the Promise using `then([callback])`. This callback then populates your `vm.content` variable in your controller, with the data passed in the response.

You can read more about the `$http` provider in the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

When you want to render your content somewhere, you would do something like this:

```
<span>{{baseCtrl.content}}</span>
```

Although that part depends highly on what content you're presenting.

You should probably separate the `fetchContent()` function into an Angular service, but that's an entirely different topic.

Comment: very well done, and more documented than my accepted answer, it was just that answer that gave the broad and for me working method, but thank you also, very much!

Comment: @OliverWilliams That you got an answer that helped you is the important part. Doesn't really matter who provided that answer.